# How to query solr for entries that miss a optionally (or) queried field

Tags: solr

Assuming the following indexed data:

```
[ uid: 1, hide_nav: false]
[ uid: 2, hide_nav: true, show_anyway: true]
[ uid: 3, hide_nav: true, show_anyway: false]
```

I want to query all entries which:

```
hide_nav:false OR
(hide_nav:true AND show_anyway: true)
```

using the filter query

```
(-hide_nav:true) A (hide_nav:true AND show_anyway:true)
```

However, this just gives me entry (2) but NOT entry (1), probably because (1) is missing the field **show_anyway** and although the 2nd part of the OR query should not be relevant for the entry, it somehow is.

What am I missing?

I am aware that I could just add the **show_anyway** field to all entries, but this is not an option for other reasons.

Comment: Why aren't you using the first query, instead of the negated one? (i.e. does `hide_nav:false OR (hide_nav:true AND show_anyway: true)` give the correct result? The inverse variant would be `(*:* -hide_nav:true) OR `hide_nav:true AND show_anyway:true`), but unless you have other options than `true` or `false`, should be the exact same as the first query (`*:* -hide_nav:true` would represent the same set of documents as `hide_nav:false` if `true` and `false` are the only possible values).

Comment: The reason why the behavior changes in your second query is because you have a purely negative query first, and while Solr usually appends the set of all documents in front of a purely negative query, that does not happen when there are multiple terms involved. So you're effectively querying for only `(hide_nav:true AND show_anyway:true)` in that case. Appending `*:*` - the set representing all documents` in front so you have something to subtract the other set of matching documents from (the negative query) makes that set actually contain documents, and you get the behavior you expect.

Comment: Removing the negation does the trick. Thanks for the inside too.